# Linear transformation in polar coordinates

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

An exercise from Prof. Strang's [course](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-06sc-linear-algebra-fall-2011/positive-definite-matrices-and-applications/linear-transformations-and-their-matrices/MIT18_06SCF11_Ses3.6prob.pdf): consider the transformation $T$ that doubles the distance between each point and the origin without changing the direction from the origin to the points. In polar coordinates this is described by $T(r, \theta)=(2r, \theta)$. Is $T$ a linear transformation? Find the matrix of $T$.

The answer given is yes and $2I$.

---

I have two questions:

1. I do think $T$ is a linear transformation since it is independent of coordinates. However, I think the matrix of $T$ should be $
    \begin{bmatrix}
     2 & 0 \\
     0 & 1
    \end{bmatrix}
   $;
2. If I can find linear transformations under both polar coordinates and Cartesian coordinates, why the transformation of these two coordinates are not linear transformation?

Comment: “Independent of coordinates” (at least as far as I can make out what you mean by that here) does not make for a linear transformation: consider the map $T: (r,\theta)\mapsto (1/r,\theta)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your reasoning in (1) is incorrect. It doesn't make sense to say "$T$ is independent of coordinates hence linear", because there is absolutely no link between the concepts of "coordinate-independence" (which is an intuitive term, but a little tough to make rigorous) and "linearity". Here's how to get the answer:

You're considering the function $T: \Bbb{R}^2 \to \Bbb{R}^2$, which doubles the distance of each point from the origin along the same direction. More precisely, given any point $(x,y)$ of the domain, $T(x,y)$ is supposed to be a point on the same line through the origin, but with double the distance,. Since $T(x,y)$ lies on the same line as $(x,y)$, there is some $\lambda \in \Bbb{R}$ such that
\begin{align}
T(x,y) = \lambda \cdot (x,y)
\end{align}
The additional condition you're imposing on $T$ is that it has to double the distance. This immediately implies that $\lambda^2 = 4$; since you want it to be in the same direction, you have to choose a positive $\lambda$; hence $\lambda = 2$. Thus, we have deduced that for all $(x,y) \in \Bbb{R}^2$,
\begin{align}
T(x,y) = 2 \cdot (x,y)
\end{align}
Or equivalently, $T= 2 I_{\Bbb{R}^2}$. Since the identity is linear, $T$ is also clearly linear. This implies that the matrix of $T$ with respect to standard basis is twice the identity matrix.

---

The above explanation tells you what and how to get the correct answer, but it doesn't say why your thought process and reasoning was wrong; I'll try to explain this now.

First of all, to keep these concepts straight in your mind, I think it is very misleading  (for yourself) to write statements like "a linear transformation in polar coordinates" (it is clear what you mean of course, but I always have the impression that poor choice of words leads to self-confusion). A linear transformation is a linear transformation. That's it. By definition, it is a function $T$ between two vector spaces, which is linear; it doesn't matter what "coordinates" you use. It is something defined based solely on the vector space structure of the domain and target space.

The very first "misconception" I'd like to address is regarding notation.
From a purely logical perspective, just because you use the symbols $r$ and $\theta$, it doesn't automatically make things "polar coordinates", and just because you use the symbols $x,y$ it doesn't mean you're working in "cartesian coordinates". This should make sense, because Math doesn't care what symbols you use... Mathematics makes just as much sense if you write things in latin letters $x,y,z,a,b,c,i,j,k$ as it does in greek letters $\xi,\eta,\theta...$ or even if you decide to write everything as Chinese letters (of course it is tradition to use $x,y$ for cartesian and $r,\theta$ for polar. My point was purely logical, I'm not saying to upset hundreds of years of tradition).

Having said all that, here's how to make precise what you intended to say. Polar coordinates should be thought of as a function. Define the set $A = (0,\infty) \times (0,2\pi)$ and $B = \Bbb{R}^2 \setminus \{(x,0) \in \Bbb{R}^2 : \, x \geq 0\}$, and define the function $P:A \to B$ defined by
\begin{align}
P(r,\theta) = (r \cos \theta, r \sin \theta)
\end{align}

Here, $A$ is thought of as the "space of polar-coordinate parameters" and $B$ is thought of as the "space of cartesian-coordinate parameters", and you can check that the function $P$ is bijective, so it allows you to translate back and forth between the two spaces of parameters.

You made the statement that

> In polar coordinates, this is described by $T(r, \theta) = (2r, \theta)$

This is understandable to me, but the more precise way of saying it is the following:

> For every $(r,\theta) \in A$, the function $T: \Bbb{R}^2 \to \Bbb{R}^2$ is such that
> \begin{align}
> (P^{-1} \circ T \circ P)(r,\theta) = (2r, \theta)
> \end{align}

Composing with $P^{-1}$ and $P$ is what allows you to state things in terms of polar coordinates. The way to "read" the formula above is that given a point $(r,\theta)$ in "polar-coordinate space", $P(r,\theta)$ gives you a point in the domain of $T$, then after applying $T$ to $P(r,\theta)$, we apply $P^{-1}$ to describe it back in terms of "polar coordinate space".

Now, there is always a problem with polar coordinates. The function $P$ that I defined above is clearly not linear (in general $P(2r,2\theta) \neq 2 P(r,\theta)$). A second issue with polar coordinates is that the domain and target space of the function $P$ is the set $A$ and $B$, which is not the entire $\Bbb{R}^2$.

Often times people are too lazy to write out the hidden compositions with $P$ and $P^{-1}$, so they just say "in polar coordinates $T(r,\theta) = \dots$" as opposed to the more precise statement "for every $(r,\theta) \in A$, $(P^{-1} \circ T \circ P)(r,\theta) = \dots$". So, my suggestion to you is to always define $T$ first. Then if you want to "descibe $T$ in another coordinate system" (for example cylindrical coordinates if you are in $3D$), then you need to compose with the appropiate coordinate transformation function.

---

**Edit In response to Comment**

Let's say $\alpha = (r\cos\theta, r\sin\theta)\in\Bbb{R}^2$ is the point of interest. Let $V:= T_{\alpha}\Bbb{R}^2$, this is the vector space we're interested in. The two bases $B_{\text{cart}}$ and $B_{\text{polar}}$ are both bases for the same vector space $V$, which implies there is a linear isomorphism $L:V\to V$ which maps one basis onto the other:
\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
L((e_1)_{\alpha}):= (\hat{r})_{\alpha} &= \cos\theta \cdot (e_1)_{\alpha} + \sin\theta \cdot (e_2)_{\alpha}\\
L((e_2)_{\alpha}):= (\hat{\theta})_{\alpha} &= -\sin\theta \cdot (e_1)_{\alpha} + \cos\theta \cdot (e_2)_{\alpha}
\end{cases}
\end{align}

As for an example of a non-linear function giving rise to linear approximations, consider the following example. In $1$-D, lets say $f(x) = e^{3\sin x}$. Then, $f'(x) = 3\cos(x) e^{3\sin x}$. Now, be careful, I'm not saying that the function $x\mapsto f'(x) = 3\cos(x) e^{3\sin x}$ is linear, of course it isn't, this is a highly non-linear function. Instead, what I mean is that if you pick a particular value for $x$, and consider the function $Df_x:\Bbb{R}\to \Bbb{R}$ defined as
\begin{align}
Df_x(h)&:= f'(x) \cdot h = (3\cos(x) e^{3\sin x})\cdot h
\end{align}
then this is certainly a linear function (of $h$). To make this even more concrete, let's say $x=0$. Then, $f'(0) = 3$, so $Df_0(h) = f'(0)\cdot h = 3h$.

In higher dimensions, we have a similar story. Let's consider $f:\Bbb{R}^2\to \Bbb{R}$ defined as $f(x,y) = x^2 + e^{xy}$. Then, If you've taken a course in multivariable calculus, you should know the Jacobian matrix at a point $(x,y)$ is
\begin{align}
f'(x,y) &=
\begin{bmatrix}
2x + ye^{xy} & x e^{xy}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
In other words, the derivative (which at any given point is a linear transformation) is $Df_{(x,y)}:\Bbb{R}^2\to \Bbb{R}$, given by
\begin{align}
Df_{(x,y)}(h,k) &= (2x+ye^{xy})h + (e^{xy})k.
\end{align}
This is once again a linear function of $(h,k)$. Again, being even more concrete, observe that if $(x,y) = (1,1)$ then $Df_{(1,1)}(h,k)= (2+e)\cdot h +e\cdot k $, which is clearly linear (as a function of $(h,k)$).

Comment: May I ask a seeming stupid question: does linear transformation exists in polar-coordinate space?

Comment: @Tengerye No it doesn't. To talk about linear transformations, you need 3 pieces of information. First, you need a vector space $V$ as the domain, second you need a vector space $W$ as the target, and third you need the actual linear function $T:V \to W$. The problem with "polar-coordinate space", for which I used the notation $A = (0,\infty) \times (0,2\pi)$, is that $A$ is NOT a vector space, so you cannot have a linear transformation defined on $A$. It's kind of like me asking you to make a sandwich without giving you any bread (it's not only impossible, it doesn't even make logical sense).

Comment: What you can talk about is a REPRESENTATION of a linear transformation in terms of polar coordinates. i.e it's basically what I wrote above. If $T$ is your linear transformation, and if $P$ is the polar-coordinate transformation function (like I defined above), then you can call $P^{-1} \circ T \circ P$ the representation of $T$ in terms of polar-coordinates. As a $3D$ example, if $S: \Bbb{R}^3 \to \Bbb{R}^3$ is a linear transformation, and $C(r,\theta,z) = (r\cos \theta, r \sin \theta, z)$ is the cylindrical coordinate map, then you can say  (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) $C^{-1} \circ S \circ C$ is the cylindrical coordinate representation of the linear transformation $S$. I hope you understand the difference between a linear transformation, and its representation in different coordinates.

Comment: @peek-a-boo so will a change of basis from cartesian to polar coordinates be a linear transformation or not. And what about if the transformation is defined at just a point ( in terms of differentials)

Comment: @Shashaank The function $P$ which I defined above is certainly not linear. However, what you can consider is this: fix a point $\alpha\in \Bbb{R}^2$. Then, we can consider the tangent space to $\Bbb{R}^2$ at the point $\alpha$, $T_{\alpha}\Bbb{R}^2$ (think of this pictorially as just a copy of $\Bbb{R}^2$ but with all the vectors "starting at the point $\alpha$"). Now you can relate two sets of basis vectors $B_{\text{cart}}=\{(e_1)_{\alpha}, (e_2)_{\alpha}\}$, which is the so called "cartesian" basis, and the basis $B_{\text{polar}}=\{(\hat{r})_{\alpha}, (\hat{\theta})_{\alpha}\}$ (cont)

Comment: where $B_{\text{polar}}$ is what you might call the polar coordinate basis vectors. In this case, there is a unique linear transformation $L:T_{\alpha}\Bbb{R}^2\to T_{\alpha}\Bbb{R}^2$ which maps the cartesian basis vectors onto the polar basis vectors. Essentially, the message is that the actual polar coordinates function $P$ is NOT linear, however, this function $P$ gives rise to a linear transformation $L$ defined on the tangent spaces.

Comment: This should even heuristically make sense: in general calculus is about non-linear stuff, but derivatives at a point are pretty much defined as linear approximations to your non-linear function at that point (and roughly speaking, tangent spaces at a point are defined as local linear approximations to the manifold), so it should make sense that every (differentiable) non-linear function gives rise to a linear mapping between tangent spaces. (edit: I see that Ted Shifrin has told you pretty much the same thing in the other comment :) )

Comment: @peek-a-boo many thanks for this. Yes I see I am getting the point. As just for a perfect clarification could you please help me by providing the following - 1) could you please write what a transformation from cartesian to polar be in context of linear algebra ( like how it will be represented in the form $T(ca + b) \neq cT(a) + T(b) $ ; what will be there in the place of $a$ and $b$) 2) could you please give an example of a non linear function in calculus giving rise to a linear mapping ( by differentiation). I just want to see a practical example and things will be very clear then. Thanks

Comment: @Shashaank I've updated my answer. By the way, if you're studying differential geometry for the purposes of GR, I would HIGHLY recommend you watch Frederic Schuller's lectures on youtube (the beginning covers all the necessary topology, linear/multi-linear algebra, and the basics of differential geometry)

Comment: @peek-a-boo many thanks 1) yes I plan to Fredrick Schuller's lectures, have heard about them. 2) ok I get that, so the differential at a given point is just a number so df written upto just first order in differential ( say dx in 1D or dx dy in 2D ) has to be linear ( of course only when it's written at a point. At different points the "constant factors" would be different making it a 'different ' linear function. Right. That's the crux. 3) got a bit confused by the 1st example you have give. Linear Transformations are written ( formally) in abstract vector form. What I am asking is that I can

Comment: change my basis and write a change of basis transformation as a matrix. The operator for the change of basis is Identity operator $I :R^2-> R^2. $ I want to see what this change from cartesian to polar will like. And What will be it's matrix in those two basis. Also what you have written that there exists an linear isomorphism. I want to ask that, that isomorphism holds for just one point right if the isomorphism has to be linear. It will change with theta. If you write simply the isomorphism that you have calculated as matrix you will get the rotation matrix ( cont)

Comment: That matrix if it has to denote a linear transformation ( isomorphism) then it will depict the change at just that single point. Because the polar basis vectors will change at different points and then $\cos() and sin() $ will not be linear. So if the isomorphism has to be linear it has to depict the change at just a point where cos and sin are constant. Is that right. Would you please just lastly help in this too, it would be quite clear to me then. But apart from that thanks for your edit. I have voted it too and thanks for suggestion of Schuller's lecture.

Comment: @Shashaank yes that's right. If you go to a different point, then you'll end up with a different linear transformation. For your second question, a linear transformation is a linear transformation, that's it. The change of basis isomorphism is NOT the identity. The MATRIX REPRESENTATION depends on which basis you're calculating relative to. In my example, $L$ is NOT the identity operator, but if we look at $[L]_{B_{\text{cart}}}^{B_\text{polar}}$, this is the identity matrix. However, if you consider $[L]_{B_{\text{cart}}}^{B_{\text{cart}}}$, then you get the matrix of $\cos$ and $\sin$.

Comment: @peek-a-boo yes I got. And in your last comment both the matrices that you write, do both of them represent the transformation at a single point or not ( because cartesian to polar transformation is not linear but if you consider the transformation at just a point then it should be linear). Could you please confirm whether both the matrices you have written in your last comment are representing the transformation at just a single point or not. Thanks..

Comment: @Shashaank yes everything is being done at one point.

Comment: @peek-a-boo thanks

Comment: @peek-a-boo I watched the multilinear algebra lecture of schuller that you recommended. There he says that the inner product of 2 polynomials is a (0, 2 ) tensor. But we know inner product is an invariant, right, it is a scalar. Should I ask a new question or is it too naive. How can the inner product be a (0, 2) tensor. The metric is a (0, 2) tensor. The inner product was always a scalar. Isn't it.

Comment: @Shashaank Let's say $V$ is a vector space over $\Bbb{R}$. Then, the inner product is a function $T:V \times V \to \Bbb{R}$, which is bilinear (and symmetric and positive-definite) hence inner products are $(0,2)$ tensors. It is the OUTPUT of an inner product which is a real number, but the inner product itself (which is a function as I mentioned above) is a $(0,2)$ tensor.

Comment: @peek-a-boo so the quantity that we use and call in physics the inner product ( eg inner product of Force and work or any other quantity where you can take the inner product of 2 vectors and where we don't need to use a bilinear form like the metric), what is that. Is it a scalar or not. And a related thing in linear algebra is - when we choose a basis {e_1, e_2, _3} over V with field R and write it as {(1,0,0), (0,1,0) , (0,0,1)} the " Numbers 1,0" in for eg: (1, 0,0) are scalars in R or is it just a representation. Since if we study $C$ with field R we say a basis is {1, i} but i is not in R

Comment: @shashank this is getting too long, and unrelated to the original question; you should ask a new one

Answer (score 0):

1) The matrix of $T$ should be $\begin{bmatrix}
  2 & 0 \\
  0 & 2
 \end{bmatrix}
$.

This is because the length in the $x$-direction is multiplied by $2$, and the length in the $y$-direction is multiplied by $2$. To see this write $r = (\cos \theta, \sin \theta)$, so $2r = 2(\cos \theta, \sin \theta) = (2\cos \theta, 2\sin \theta)$.

Therefore $\hat{i}$ moves to $\begin{pmatrix}
  2 \\
  0
 \end{pmatrix}
$ and $\hat{j}$ moves to $\begin{pmatrix}
  0 \\
  2
 \end{pmatrix}
$, which gives the above matrix.

2) Your intuition might have been wrong, as suggested in amd's comment. The best strategy is to check through the three conditions needed for a linear transformation:

$$1) \ T(\textbf{u} + \textbf{v}) = T(\textbf{u}) + T(\textbf{v})$$
$$2) \ T(k \textbf{v}) = k T(\textbf{v}) $$

I'll leave this part to you.

Comment: Maybe the first check condition is redundant? :D

Comment: Yes, for $T(0) = 0$ I was thinking about subspaces.

Answer (score 0):

1) The matrix $T=2I$ is the transformation in  cartesian coordinates. The other one works for points expressed in polar coordinates.

2) The transformation from cartesians to polars is not linear because if it were, then it wouldn't make sense to transform problems because the arithmetic properties would remain the same. The change of coordinates helps simplify some calculations, like on this problem, if you look at it in cartesians, the distance from the origin to the point is $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ which is an expression hard to work with, but in polars it is just $r$.

Comment: Polar coordinates are most definitely non-linear (and, in addition, not globally defined).

Comment: Can I say if $T$, which is a linear transformation in polar-coordinate space, is unlikely to be linear transformation in Cartesian-coordinate space?@TedShifrin

Comment: @TedShifrin so will a change of basis from cartesian to polar coordinates be a linear transformation or not. And what about if the transformation is defined at just a point ( in terms of differentials)

Comment: @Shashaank Look at the formula. Trig functions and square root are not linear. The derivative at a point is always a linear transformation. You might check out my YouTube lectures, linked in my profile.

Comment: @TedShifrin  thank you I got it now. Apart from YouTube lectures I will particularly like to look at at your differential geometry textbook since I am studying General Relativity. Would it be ok for you if I have any doubt in it and mail you regarding that ( as you have written in the profile for the lectures)

Comment: @Shashaank You can post questions here or find me in chat.

Comment: @TedShifrin ok thanks